# Is stacking bare hard drives on top of one another safe?

Tags: hard-drive

I have several bare (not in an enclosure) hard drives that need to be stored for an extended period of time. Will stacking them on top of one another cause any problems in terms of data being lost or corrupted?

Comment: I'd put them in antistatic bags and separate them by pieces of cardbord, just in case. Not a real answer, as I don't have any observations or theoretical knowledge about what might happen otherwise, but what I've suggested is not expensive and is unlikely to cause extra issues.

Comment: My brother stores drives like that (has for over 15 years), I have pulled drives out of a stack after 8 years or more, they work just fine with data intact. If data is critical it should be stored on more than one device or place.

Comment: With older drives you did need to be worried about G forces, and sometimes the force of the drive simply "clacking" against another was enough to damage it.  But this is not so critical with modern devices.  That said, you wouldn't want one drive to come sliding off the other and crash to the ground, or ever fall several inches, for that matter, so use some care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than scratching to exterior of the drives you should be fine. Be careful of extreme temperatures, static electricity and moisture.

If you are worried about electromagnetic issues, read [here](http://cobolhacker.com/2006/10/28/is-it-possible-to-erase-a-hard-drive-with-magnets/).